# Contar os options disabled de um select com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Boas, como posso contar os options com a opção disabled selecionada e de forma eficiente com jquery?

Comment: Coloque o que você já tentou fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisas de jQuery para isso. Podes fazer só com JavaScript e seletor CSS `:disabled`

```js
const nrA = document.querySelectorAll('option:disabled').length;
console.log('A', nrA);

const nrB = $('option:disabled').length;
console.log('B', nrB);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana" disabled>Banana</option>
    <option value="Orange" disabled>Orange</option>
    <option value="Grape">Grape</option>
</select>
```

Comment: obrigado, pela resposta! Com jquery diminui-se o tamanho do código tornando-o mais eficiente.

Comment: @MusicLyricsHQ se a tua página fizer tudo sem jQuery aí sim é mais eficiente pois jQuery carrega muitas linhas de código para fazer coisas simples como esta.

Comment: a minha página tem várias utilizações de jquery

Comment: No inicio você diz que `"Não precisas de jQuery para isso."` e  depois a resposta é com Jquery!! De castigo, não vou lhe passar link de Sol De Janeiro - Live in South Korea :(

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo haha :) Eu disse que era melhor sem, mas o pedido na pergunta era **com**, por isso dei as duas.

Comment: +1 e vai lá então, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rr7TaaJ60Ws

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples de contar usando jQuery:

```js
conta = $('select option:disabled').length;
console.log(conta);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="1" disabled="disabled">A</option>
    <option value="2" disabled="disabled">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4" disabled="disabled">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: muito boa, direta e reta, +1